# How To Display In A List Using PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller, html-lists

How do you repeatedly display the ID numbers in PHP then in a list?

This is the code I have in View

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><?php echo ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

In Controller

```
$query=$this->mdl_mainmenu->notif_items();
$data['notifs'] = $query;
$this->load->view('vw_main_menu',$data);
```

In Model

```
function notif_items(){
    $user = $this->session->userdata("username");
    $this->csbrms->select("deleted_user_request.sdp_no,
                            deleted_user_request.approval_status");

    $this->csbrms->from('deleted_user_request');
    $this->csbrms->join('m_employee_masters', 'm_employee_masters.emp_no = user_request.emp_no'); 
    $this->csbrms->where('deleted_user_request.created_by',$user);
    $this->csbrms->where('deleted_user_request.approval_status' , 'Closed');
    $this->csbrms->where('deleted_user_request.approval_status' , 'Resolved');

    $query = $this->csbrms->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: `<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <?php foreach ($data['notifs'] as $dat){?>
  <li><a href="#"><?php echo $dat; ?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>`. `foreach` may changed accordingly based on structure of `$data`, As we don't know what's its structure and how's it look like

Comment: sorry it's `$vw_main_menu['notifs']` there rather than `$data`

Answer (score 0):

changed ul tag to :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <?php foreach($vw_main_menu['notifs'] as $row):?>
      <li>
         <a href="#"><?php echo $row['deleted_user_request.sdp_no']?></a>
      </li>
   <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <?php foreach($notifs as $row):?>
      <li>
         <a href="#"><?php echo $row->deleted_user_request.sdp_no; ?></a>
      </li>
   <?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```